# Big vacation in Australia

Tags: australia, vacations

I moved to Australia have been one year. Many guys here get a holiday of 3, 6 or 12 months.

How it works. I'm Brazilian and in Brazil is normal to take one month off. In Portugal when I lived is normal get some days of holiday but never more then one month.

I think isn't the time to ask my boss about a big holiday. But I wanna know how it works.

If I lost the job, or I just don't receive my salary at I back.

Comment: This might be better on Workplace.SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3, 6 or 12 monts of "holiday" is most definitely not normal paid vacation anywhere except in extreme circumstances (a brother of a friend of mine recently had a 3 month vacation after having almost none the 2 years before due to a quickly growing business). There are basically 3 ways to get a multi-month holiday:

- A [sabbattical leave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatical) is something employers offer as an employee retention measure, usually it's unpaid leave but with a guarantee that you'll get the same job when you come back.
- Between jobs. If you want to switch jobs, have the money and are certain that you can find a new job easily, you just leave your current one, go on holiday and look for a new one when you come back (or maybe you already have it with a contract starting in a few months).
- Be self-employed. When and how long you go on vacation is completely your own decision, you just have to be reasonably sure that finding clients won't be too hard afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal in Australia to be entitled to 4 weeks of annual leave after you have worked for the same company full time for one year.  You can then negotiate a time to take this leave with your boss.

If you have worked for less than a year, generally you are entitled to no leave.  However, your boss may allow you to access some of the leave. e.g. after 6 months they may allow you to take 2 weeks of leave.

Ultimately this should be stated in your employment contract or the award under which you are employed.